# How to secure OWIN Self-Host WebAPI using client certificates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, client-certificates

### Background

We are currently building a RESTful service using Web API 2 and .NET 4.5.2.
The service is leveraging OWIN self-hosting, embedded in a windows service using Topshelf. In order to authenticate, the clients have to provide a client certificate (X509). All documentation we found so far uses IIS to setup the client certificate authentication.

### Question

Is there are proper way to authenticate via certificates, when usuing OWIN self-hosting instead of IIS?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a trail I'm just starting down. Check out the Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ClientCertificates [NuGet package][1] or [github repo][2]. I may post an answer once I've got it working in my project.

    [1]: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ClientCertificates/
    [2]: https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/source/Owin.ClientCertificates